# Apache VirtualHost issue veeery slow

Tags: performance, windows-7, apache2, virtualhost

I just installed on Windows7, Apache2.2.17, PHP5.3.5. PC connected to LAN. I have configure vhosts, like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/www/tm"
    ServerName tm
    ServerAlias www.tm
    ErrorLog "logs/tm-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/tm-access.log" common

    <directory "C:/www/tm">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And in 'hosts' file I just add line at the end: '192.168.0.55 tm' (my LAN-IP). If I type in address http://tm - it opens fine! And it work fast and it work fine!

But if I try to do this from other computer on same LAN, (with added record to hosts file), it opens verry verry slooooow. (phpinfo() page opens ~ 1 min)

Windows Firewall turned off on both machines. Net works fine. Ping PC-to-PC fine!
Any ideas? (IPV6 turned off in LocalLan connection)

Comment: I don't think it's an apache config issue, do you have the same performance issue when you try http://192.168.0.55 from the other machines ?